# Start and end of stroke animation

Tags: css, svg, css-animations

[image][image: The stroke-dasharray animation start and end states]

What I want is in green And what I already have Is in red in the image. And I want it to be done in *CSS* animation. The edge of the triangle (start and end of stroke) should be angled like in picture.

My so far code is :

```css
.path {
  stroke-dasharray: 504;
  animation: dash 2.5s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: dash 2.5s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: dash 2.5s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: dash 2.5s linear infinite -o-animation: dash 2.5s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes dash {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    stroke-width: 30;
  }
  50% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 500;
    stroke-width: 30;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
    stroke-width: 30;
  }
}
div svg {
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 252.7 251.9" style="enable-background:new 0 0 252.7 251.9;" xml:space="preserve">
    <style type="text/css">
      .st0 {
        fill: #fff;
      }
    </style>
    <g>
      <path stroke="#C5C5C5" stroke-width="20" stroke-linejoin="square" stroke-linecap="butt" class="path" d="M151 45 L79 200 L213 200 L152.324 50 L156 45" fill="url(#fagl)" />
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: It will be good of you put a fiddle..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue you are facing is the way the stoke end is rendered. I am not aware of a way to make it end exaclty at the angle you need. None of the [stoke-linecap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-linecap) values would fit.
*You should also note that the path element in your SVG doesn't have the same start and end points.*

**Workaround:**

A way would be to make the path go further than you need it and hide the overflow with [clipPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath). This way, the sroke will end at the desired angle:

```css
.path {
  stroke-dasharray: 23;
  animation: dash 2.5s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes dash {
  to { stroke-dashoffset: -46; }
}
svg { width: 20%; }
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 10 10">
  <clipPath id="clip">
    <path d="M5 1 L8 9 H2z" />
  </clipPath>
  <path stroke="#C5C5C5" stroke-width="2" class="path" d="M5 1 L8 9 H2 L5 1" fill="url(#fagl)" clip-path="url(#clip)" />
</svg>
```

*Note that I also simplified your SVG and CSS*

Answer (score 1):

If you change the `45` values to `60` (the degrees) in your `path` it will give you the output you desired AFAICT

#### Snippet

```css
.path {
  stroke-dasharray: 504;
  animation: dash 2.5s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: dash 2.5s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: dash 2.5s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: dash 2.5s linear infinite -o-animation: dash 2.5s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes dash {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    stroke-width: 30;
  }
  50% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 500;
    stroke-width: 30;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
    stroke-width: 30;
  }
}
div svg {
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 252.7 251.9" style="enable-background:new 0 0 252.7 251.9;" xml:space="preserve">
    <style type="text/css">
      .st0 {
        fill: #fff;
      }
    </style>
    <g>
      <path stroke="#C5C5C5" stroke-width="20" stroke-linejoin="square" stroke-linecap="butt" class="path" d="M151 60 L79 200 L213 200 L152.324 50 L156 60" fill="url(#fagl)" />
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Not as far as I can see.